# compilation failed:out of range at offset 590

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use this reg_expression to validate URLs:

```
  $pattern='/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}
  \x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-   
  9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.
  (\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|
  [\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0- 
  \xFFEF])
  ([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])*([a-z]
  |\d|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])))\.)*(([a-z]|[\x{00A0}-\
  x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])|(([a-z]|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}
  \x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x{00A0}-\
  x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])*([a-z]|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-
  \x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])))\.?)
  (:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])
  |(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|
  [\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&\'\  
  (\)\*\+,;=]|:
  |@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}- 
  \x{FFEF}])|
  (%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}]|\/|\?)*)?
  (#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x{00A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-
  \x{FFEF}])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/u';
```

I got the following warning when trying to run preg_match:
**Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 590** 
After a search I made it is obvious that there is an illegal character inside a character class...but it is very difficult to pinpoint the origin of the error.

So my question comes down to this: What offset 590 means? Obviously it refers to a position within the pattern but how am I going to find it.

Comment: There are several ways, for example the most simple one would be to cut the regex in half. Try the 2 regexes, one must sureley give an error. And so on until you find the bug. Ofcourse, you must cut it right. Otherwise, just use notepad++ or any editor which tells you the position of your cursor.

Comment: Load it into Emacs. Put your cursor at the beginning of the RE, then use M-590 C-f to go 590 characters into it.

Comment: count 590 characters in from the start of your regex. Or start chopping things down until you isolate the segment that's causing the problem.

Comment: Want's wrong with `filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`?

Comment: I played a little with the code and a new offset was discovered...153, at this point here |[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0...153 is at 1 or somewhere around 1. DO you see anything wrong there? It is really frustrating to work with so huge regular expressions. The reason I am doing it?This regexp is what thw jquery validate plugin uses to validate url. I just want to use the same for server side purposes.Same pattern for client and server. But I am searching for alternatives cause I said it cumbersome.